# Setting the color of text in a textarea on the go

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning JavaScript and testing things. I have made a text-area which takes some html code and prints the result out.Its working well but I want that whenever a tag is typed like `<h1>` the color should change from white to red. This is my code which does not do so, Please help me in fixing it ..

Code:

```
<script>
    $("#_co").on("input propertychange", function(){
        $("#out").html($("#_co").val());
         var text = jQuery("#_co").val();
        if (text.contains("<")){
            text.css('color','red');
        }
    }); </script>
```

Comment: You can change the color of all the text in the textarea, but you can't change the color of just parts of the text.

Comment: Oh, I see, you have regular HTML below the textarea, kinda like stack overflow does, and you want to change the color of tags. What you should do is look into syntax highlighters, there are many available in javascript, and they mostly work great.

Comment: look into http://codemirror.net/

Comment: Ok. But is there any syntax highlighter out there which has cdn links??

Comment: can i change its appearence ?? that codemirror??

Answer (score 1):

There no direct way to achieve the same, but this would help you work around

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahendra_raje/UCLrh/2/)

Pls have a look

```
function divClicked() {
var divHtml = $(this).html();
var editableText = $("<textarea />");
editableText.val(divHtml);
$(this).replaceWith(editableText);
editableText.focus();
// setup the blur event for this new textarea
editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
var html = $(this).val();
var viewableText = $("<div>");
viewableText.html(html);
$(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
// setup the click event for this new div
viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.div").click(divClicked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this one below?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kjn3g/1/)

```
$("#dummy").blur(function(){
    var color = $(this).val()=='' ? 'red' : 'white';
     $(this).css('background-color', color);
});
```